# how to delete installation files from mac?

Tags: macos

I have macOS Mojave and accidently clicked to update the operating system to Big Sur, now i can't delete the files i downloaded ,
I have tried to delete it several times but when i click on delete after i select "Install macOS Big Sur" under system preference -> Storage -> manage ( screen shot below) , nothing happens.

how to delete this , the file is 12.45 GB.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be that the program is still running in the background.

Try opening your [Activity Monitor](https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac) (either by searching for it with `Spotlight` or navigating to `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor`). You'll see a list of currently running processes and some info about them. Scroll through the list for something with a name similar to "Install macOS Big Sur".

If you see it, double-click on the process and click `Quit` or `Force Quit`. Then try deleting the file again.

https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/quit-a-process-actmntr1002/10.14/mac/11.0